# how to read image from Sqlite according to id and display in image-view android

Tags: android, sqlite

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + INFR_TABLE
            + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," + CATEGORY + " integer,"
            + STATUS + " text, " + FEEDBACK + " text, " + DATE + " text,  "
            + IMAGE + " BLOB)");

    System.out.println("Database Createeeeeeeeeeeeeee");

}




public byte getimage( String id)

    {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(INFR_TABLE, new String[] { "_id", "cateogry",
                "status", "feedback", "date", "image" }, null, null, null,
                null, null);

        return 0;

    }
```

I am saving the Image in the database as Blob, I want to fetch a particular image base on the id but, I'm unable to fetch it in Bytes, because I have to print it in image view please help me how to fetch image from database base on the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public byte[] getimage(String id)

    {

        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(INFR_TABLE, new String[] { "_id", "cateogry",
                "status", "feedback", "date", "image" }, ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        byteImage2 = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
        // setImage(byteImage2);
        cursor.close();
        return byteImage2;

    }
```

please  add this code and enjoy ......... if any Query Update me